# jquery - select the next item of this in each() function

Tags: jquery

I want to select the next element of this in each() function. check out the code comments

```
$(function(){
    var selects = $('body').find('span');
    selects.each(function(index,el){
        if(index==0){
            //remove the next span of this, which is span2 
        }

    });
}); 


    <body>
        <div>
            <span>1</span>
        </div>
        <span>2</span>
        <div>
            <span>3</span>
        </div>  
    </body>
```

Comment: I don't really understand the new comments you've added. Can you better explain what you're trying to achieve? I have a feeling you won't be needing an `.each` loop.

Comment: nevermind. Now I know that using eq() will do most of the things I want in this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Based on your DOM structure, you can do:

```
var selects = $('body').find('span');
selects.each(function(index, el) {
    if(index !== selects.length - 1) {

        // select the next span
        alert(selects.eq(index + 1).text());
    }
});
```

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/nhhTg/)

Comment: oh so eq() function is what I need. Cheers!